# need help refactoring this method

Tags: java, refactoring

is there a more concise way to write this method? maybe with regular expressions?

```
   /**
 * Find a parameter in the request.pathInfo. In a certain cases we 
     * will send the variables via the path.
 * 
 * For example:
 *    normal request parameters - /ps/cmap?t=i&n=25&xid=1
 *    mapping via path would be - /ps/cmap/ti/n25?xid=1
 */
private static String findParamInPath(String paramName, HttpServletRequest request){
      String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo();
      int startIndex = pathInfo.indexOf("/" + paramName);
      if(startIndex >= 0){
        startIndex += (paramName.length()+1);

        int endIndex = pathInfo.indexOf("/", startIndex);
        if(endIndex < 0){
          endIndex = pathInfo.indexOf("?", startIndex);
        }
        if(endIndex < 0){
          endIndex = pathInfo.length();
        }
        String value = pathInfo.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        if (value != null) {
          return value;
        }
      }

      return null;
    }
```

Comment: First of all, remove the HttpServletRequest parameter and just pass another string, you're only using the `getPathInfo` from that object.

Comment: Add comments: what are you trying to do?

Comment: It would really help to have a few examples of "unit test" data; ie sample input and expected output.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see by reading your code that you want to extract the parameter's value, when it could be encoded as a url param or path.

Here's how you do it using regex. Notice that I've changed the method to accept String (instead of HttpServletRequest) because it's easier to code and test.

```
private static String getParamValue(String paramName, String pathInfo) {
    return pathInfo.replaceAll("^.*\\b" + paramName + "=?(.*?)(&|\\?).*$", "$1");
}
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(getParamValue("n", "/ps/cmap?t=i&n=25&xid=1"));
    System.out.println(getParamValue("n", "/ps/cmap/ti/n25?xid=1"));
}
```

And its output:

```
25
25
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bohemian,

IMO refactoring isn't about making the code shorter, but clear. Maybe the following is more clear,as readers dont need to be an regex expert to understand it:

```
private static String getParamValue(String paramName, String pathInfo) {
this.paramName = paramName;
this.pathInfo = pathInfo;

    if(paramInRequest()) 
      return valueInRequestParam(); 
    if(paramInPath())
      return valueInPathParam(); 
}

private boolean paramInRequest() {...}

private boolean paramInPath() {...}

private Strign valueInRequestParam() {...}

private Strign valueInPathParam() {...}
```